# UINavigationController to UIViewController difficulty

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

How to convert this for `UIViewController` is it possible:

```
for (UIViewController *tmpController  in [self.navigationController viewControllers]) 
{
    if ([tmpController isKindOfClass:[RootViewController class]])
    {
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:tmpController animated:YES];
        break;
    }
}
```

`[self.navigationController viewControllers]` --> how to convert this for `UIViewController`, because I'm having error,

`[self.navigationController popToViewController:tmpController animated:YES];` --> while this part i convert it to this --> `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Comment: What is the question, please be more clear

Comment: to convert this for ViewController, this is for navigation controller right?

Comment: This code looks correct.

Comment: I edited it, want to make it for viewController not navigation controller

Comment: your question is not very clear

Comment: @Omar Abdelhafith, its like this. I presented viewA then View B then View C, I use the above code to dismiss to View A because if I just use `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` it goes to view B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have ViewController A that presented ViewController B that Presented ViewController C

And you want to go back to A, do the following, in viewController C

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[[self presentingViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get hierarchy of views as follows :

```
for(UIView *view in [self.view subviews])
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Comments above I feel like you are presenting controllers like From A to B and Than B to C.

Now you want to do from C to A to do that use following code

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

**EDIT**

```
//Try this.
[[[self parentViewController] parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: I present them modally not by navigation,